# wsimport error while parsing the WSDL

Tags: wsdl

I received the below error while parsing the WSDL.

**Non unique body parts! In a port, as per BP 1.1 R2710 operations must have unique operation signaure on the wire for successful dispatch. In port HorizonWebServiceSOAP, Operations "GetTextInvitations" and "Version" have the same request body block. Try running wsimport with -extension switch, runtime will try to dispatch using SOAPAction**.

The default option for wsimport what application is using is -XdisableSSLHostnameVerification but when I have used -extension it parsed successfully.
But because of application constraint, I have to use the default option only.
Please need your help to find out what is wrong in the WSDl and what needs to be modified.

Comment: So where is the wsdl?